# How to get product price from sales order?

Tags: magento

I want to get the product price after it has been sold.
I am getting all the products from order( fetching simple products from the configurable and bundle products).I want to get the prices of simple products from sales order.

If I use

```
$item->getPrice();
```

I am not getting correct price.
Please suggest.

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app("default");

$orderNumber = 100000058;       
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderNumber);
    // get order total value
$orderValue = number_format ($order->getGrandTotal(), 2, '.' , $thousands_sep = '');
    // get order item collection
$orderItems = $order->getItemsCollection();

    $skuQtyArray = array();
    foreach ($orderItems as $item)
    {        
         $product_sku = $item->sku;
        $product_name = $item->getName();
         $product_qty = $item->getQtyOrdered();

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $product_sku);         

        $productType=$product->getTypeID();         

        if($productType=='simple')
        {                           
                echo "orderNumber = ".$orderNumber."<br/>";                         
                echo "Item_id = ".$item_id."<br/>";     
                echo "product_name = ".$product_name."<br/>";           
                echo "product_sku = ".$product_sku."<br/>";

                $skuQtVal = $product_sku."=".$product_qty;              
                $skuQtyArray[] = $skuQtVal;
        }

    }       
?>
```

**Update:**
I had asked this question long back it works with `$order->getItemsCollection();` also, that time I am not sure what was the exact issue with price.Accepted answer is also working correctly.

Comment: You're getting the "wrong" price? can you explain that? Is it without tax or is tax included? Maybe it's not a "wrong" price, only not the exact value as you need - maybe you need to calcuate it with other values. To access all properties try `var_dump($item->getData());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use - getAllItems() instead of getItemsCollection()

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the tax fields. But intuitively you use price_incl_tax.
About discount on item price in order.
If you include a discount coupon the price field doesn´t change.
Only the discount_amount field, that is the total that magento will use to fetch the values of the row of this product.